# How can I get my Stream Key through YouTube's Live API?

Tags: java, stream, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I use my own encoder to stream the video. When i stream i have to keep going back onto YouTube to change the selected stream key to use the first one that was created. How can i change or make sure that the YoutTube API uses the original stream key and not generate a new one.

I have tried using list, update and transition but none of there response give the stream key or allows me to change the stream key being used

```
        title = getStreamTitle();
        System.out.println("You chose " + title + " for stream title.");

        // Create a snippet with the video stream's title.
        LiveStreamSnippet streamSnippet = new LiveStreamSnippet();
        streamSnippet.setTitle(title);




        // Define the content distribution network settings for the
        // video stream. The settings specify the stream's format and
        // ingestion type. See:
        // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn
        CdnSettings cdnSettings = new CdnSettings();
        cdnSettings.setFormat("1080p");
        cdnSettings.setIngestionType("rtmp");
        cdnSettings.getIngestionInfo();

        LiveStream stream = new LiveStream();
        stream.setKind("youtube#liveStream");
        stream.setSnippet(streamSnippet);
        stream.setCdn(cdnSettings);


        // Construct and execute the API request to insert the stream.
        YouTube.LiveStreams.Insert liveStreamInsert =
                youtube.liveStreams().insert("snippet,cdn", stream);
        LiveStream returnedStream = liveStreamInsert.execute();
```

This is what I am currently doing to, but this create a new stream for the YouTube broadcast event. I do not want it to make a new stream but I need to return the key.

```
private static String getStreamTitle() throws IOException {

    String title = "";

    System.out.print("Please enter a stream title: ");
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    title = bReader.readLine();

    if (title.length() < 1) {
        // Use "New Stream" as the default title.
        title = "New Stream";
    }
    return title;
}
```

I either expect the output to give me a stream key which I can add to my encoder or be able to directly make it use the previous stream so the reusable stream key stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

For those who haven't seen OP's newer post, where they posted their answer, you can get the stream key using:

```
returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getStreamName();
```

[How can I change the stream my event uses via the YouTube live api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785543/how-can-i-change-the-stream-my-event-uses-via-the-youtube-live-api)

Comment: returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getStreamName();
Look like this stoped working. please Suggest if any one useing it.

I am getting exception now
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error
{
  "code" : 500,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Internal error encountered.",
  "status" : "INTERNAL"
}