# How can I change the stream my event uses via the YouTube live api?

Tags: java, youtube, streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api

So I have been looking for a way to get the 16 digit stream name from YouTube and i have finally found out how which is via this line of code ->

```
streamName = returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().getStreamName();
```

stream name is just a String

If i try use .`setStreamName();`, it does not change the stream name. i tried giving the value of my previous stream I created but the same stays the same.

If i try use `.setStreamName();`, it does not change the stream name. i tried giving the value of my previous stream I created but the same stays the same. I tried doing this ->

```
returnedStream.getCdn().getIngestionInfo().setStreamName(title);
```

but still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live broadcast is associated with a stream using a [liveBroadcasts/bind](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind) method.

In terms of Java API it would look something like this:

```
YouTube yt = ...         // your reference to YouTube
String broadcastId = ... // your broadcast Id

String newStreamId = ... // identifier of stream you want to bind
String apiKEy = ...      // your API key

// you can define other response parts if you want more or don't want some of these
String responseParts = "id,status,contentDetails.boundStreamId";

yt.liveBroadcasts().bind(broadcastId, responseParts)
    .setApiKey(apiKey)
    .setStreamId(streamId)
    // other data you might want in request
    .execute()
```

API references:

- [YouTube](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.html)
- [LiveBroadcasts.bind method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.html#bind-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
- [LiveBroadcasts.Bind request](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Bind.html)
- [Available response fields](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts#resource)

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me a lot and i was able to change the stream that was being used :-D