# how to get youtube live api stream key

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

How can I bind my YouTube stream key to match previous video.
I'm trying to use java to do it but getting no where.

I'm looking at the example given to create the broadcast stream but it doesn't have the keeping same key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten help on this before. Please try do some research on Google and then ask the question. You can see [How can I change the stream my event uses via the YouTube live api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57785543/how-can-i-change-the-stream-my-event-uses-via-the-youtube-live-api). Which will help you as it did me.

In short this was the code i received for help.

> Credit to @M. Prokhorov

```
YouTube yt = ...         // your reference to YouTube
String broadcastId = ... // your broadcast Id

String newStreamId = ... // identifier of stream you want to bind
String apiKEy = ...      // your API key

// you can define other response parts if you want more or don't want some of these
String responseParts = "id,status,contentDetails.boundStreamId";

yt.liveBroadcasts().bind(broadcastId, responseParts)
    .setApiKey(apiKey)
    .setStreamId(streamId)
    // other data you might want in request
    .execute()
```